# Parsing a nested object does not traverse the whole list with javascript

Tags: javascript, nested-loops

I'm trying to parse a nested object of the format:

```
const obj = {
  "and": [
      {
        "!=": [
          {
            "var": "name"
          },
          "name1"
        ]
      },
      {
        "in": [
          {
            "var": "hobbies"
          },
          "jogging, video games"
        ]
      }
    ]
};
```

I created a function to parse it:

```
const isOperatorCode(code) => {
  const allowedOperatorCodes = ['in', '<=', '!=', '=='];
  return allowedOperatorCodes.includes(code);
}

const parseObject = (arg, result={}) => {
  if (arg === undefined || arg === null) return arg;

  if (arg.constructor === Object && Object.keys(arg).length) {
    for (const key in arg) {
      const value = arg[key];
      if (key === 'and' || key === 'or' || key === '!') {
        result.operator = key === '!' ? 'not' : key;
        result.operands = [];
        return parseObject(value, result);
      }
      if (isOperatorCode(key)) {
        const newItem = {
          operator: key,
          attribute: value[0].var,
          value: value[1]
        }

        result.operands.push(newItem);

      }
    }
  }

  if(Array.isArray(arg) && arg.length) {
    for (const k of arg) {
      return parseObject(k, result);
    }
  }
  return result;
  
}
```

I got this result when I executed the function:

```
{"operator":"and","operands":[{"operator":"!=","attribute":"name","value":"name1"}]}

it should be:

{"operator":"and","operands":[{"operator":"!=","attribute":"name","value":"name1"}, {"operator":"in","attribute":"hobbies","value":"sport, video games"}]}
```

I know that the array does not keep the trace of the elements to continue looping through the different items. Any idea or suggestions to keep the track of the array elements and loop on them all?

Comment: What is `isOperatorCode`?

Comment: it's a simple function to check if the operator exist in the list of the allowed operatorCodes.

Comment: What are the allowed codes?

Comment: I updated the question and I added a simple function to make things clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `return` only at the very-end, you will get your expected result.

```js
const obj = {
  "and": [{
    "!=": [{
      "var": "name"
    }, "name1"]
  }, {
    "in": [{
      "var": "hobbies"
    }, "jogging, video games"]
  }]
};

const isOperatorCode = (code) => {
  const allowedOperatorCodes = ['in', '<=', '!=', '=='];
  return allowedOperatorCodes.includes(code);
}

const parseObject = (arg, result = {}) => {
  if (arg === undefined || arg === null) return arg;
  if (arg.constructor === Object && Object.keys(arg).length) {
    for (const key in arg) {
      const value = arg[key];
      if (key === 'and' || key === 'or' || key === '!') {
        result.operator = key === '!' ? 'not' : key;
        result.operands = [];
        parseObject(value, result);
      }
      if (isOperatorCode(key)) {
        const newItem = {
          operator: key,
          attribute: value[0].var,
          value: value[1]
        }
        result.operands.push(newItem);
      }
    }
  }
  if (Array.isArray(arg) && arg.length) {
    for (const k of arg) {
      parseObject(k, result);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(parseObject(obj));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 2):

`return parseObject(k, result);` stops execution of the loop so you're only going to get the first item.

```js
for (const k of arg) {
  return parseObject(k, result); // return breaks out of the loop. Only processes the first item.
}
```

Perhaps this would make more sense?

```js
  return args.map(k => parseObject(k, result)); // process all entries, return an array.
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a recursive approach with look at objects with `var` as key.

```js
const
    convert = object => {
        if (!object || typeof object !== 'object') return object;
        const [operator, values] = Object.entries(object)[0];

        return values[0] && typeof values[0] === 'object' && 'var' in values[0]
            ? { operator, attribute: values[0].var, value: values[1] }
            : { operator, operands: values.map(convert) };
    },
    object = { and: [{ "!=": [{ var: "name" }, "name1"] }, { in: [{ var: "hobbies" }, "jogging, video games"] }] },
    result = convert(object);

   console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```